# Getting blank page when React App is deployed and hosted by firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am getting a blank page when I go to my website domain after deploying it through firebase - I know what I did wrong which was I said (yes) to the option of overwriting my index/html file when running firebase init.

I have tried to solve it through various methods, I have replaced the index.html file in the build folder that firebase produced with my original and added in the required base and script tags so now at least the blank page loading and the React App name and sign in tab shows that it is loading it up. However the contents aren't displaying.

I have tried changing my firebase.json to ["hosting": {"public": "dist",] as it was originally ["hosting": {"public": "build",] however this has not worked as I get this error on the cmd: Error: Specified public directory 'dist' does not exist, can't deploy hosting to site...

Relevant code is below if you need any more snippet please comment so.

Build/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <base href="https://contact-form-fba60.firebaseapp.com/">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://contact-form-fba60.firebaseapp.com/runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://contact-form-fba60.firebaseapp.com/main.2eb2046276073df361f7.js" ></script>
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json (not sure if you need it)

```
{
  "name": "my-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "firebase": "^8.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should select 'N' while rewriting urls to index.html

Comment: So just to clarify, to do that I need to do the whole process over again? as in firebase init - and if so I do need to delete all my firebase files that were created and create a new build folder?

Comment: Yes. You should re-initiate the firebase hosting build folder.

Comment: So basically I kept my "public":"build" and then re ran npm run build and then did firebase deploy - my website now shows up at https://contact-form-fba60.web.app - but not at my domain name msdevelop.co.uk. Have you encountered this issue before?

Comment: You can connect that domain in firebase developer console in browser.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

Comment: Thanks you Stefan!

Comment: Accept my answer if it worked for you so that others can refer to this in the future.

Comment: I dont know how to accept your answer

Comment: You can see green tick icon under my the number at the left of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select 'N' while rewriting URLs to index.html.

So, I suggest you redo the firebase initialization.

Answer (score 0):

try "public": "./"

Comment: it would improve the quality of your answer if you explained why you believe your suggestion would help the OP. Thank you

Comment: Just tried this but did not change the blanks screen

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable, that's needed by webpack to build the bundle.

In the generated html you should NOT have `%PUBLIC_URL%` string in the `build /index.html` file e.g: `<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />`, it should have a full url e.g: `<link rel="icon" href="https://<your-app-name>.firebaseapp.com/favicon.ico" />`

To fix it:

**Github Part:**

1. Go to your repo in Githup, and click on repo `settings`.
2. On the repo settings sidebar, expand `Secrets and variables` menu item, then click on `actions`.
3. On the `Actions secrets and variables` page, click on `Variables` tab, then click on `New repository variable`.
4. On the `Actions variables / New variable` page, fill `Name` with `PUBLIC_URL`, and `Value` with `https://<your-app-name>.firebaseapp.com` then click on `Add variable`.

**Repo Code Part:**

1. open `.github/workflows/firebase-hosting-merge.yml` and add

```
env:
  PUBLIC_URL: ${{ vars.PUBLIC_URL }}
```

above `name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge` line.

2. commit the changes and push.

**NOTE**: Make sure set firebase hosting public directory  to `build` in `firebase.json` file.

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

I hope this will fix the issue.